# Transfer of Accounts and its related information

Tags: account, activities, ownership

I need to transfer like 2000-3000 accounts from X to Y. I should also transfer its related contacts, tasks, activities and everything that is present on the account. These accounts don't have any opportunities. What would be the best way to transfer these accounts.? I need best way to transfer these accounts and also everything associated with it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to reassign them from one user to another? Will this be a one off process or something that happens frequently?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I should transfer these accounts as part of the initial test. If successful, then we should transfer a large number of accounts. But this is only for once.

Comment: In what way are you transferring the Accounts? Is it to another org?

Comment: I highly recommend you view the following YouTube video series called [Data Import How To's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnobS_RgN7JZaD_Fq8uh3b2AA8olsj1Qk). They're brief and may very likely provide you with the answers you're looking for or else help you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, using a tool like Workbench or Dataloader to do some data updates would most likely be the easiest method for you to accomplish this.  You'll just need to export every object into a separate CSV, then change the OwnerId to from X to Y, and do a data update including the RecordId and OwnerId in your update.  After you process all Accounts, Contacts, etc. then you are done.